# How to process only last, the most relevant, events (and skip the others when latency grew too fast)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Context: Process data coming from Kafka and send back results to Kafka.

Issue: Each events could take several seconds to process (Work in progress to improve that). During that time, events (and RDD) do accumulate. Intermediate events (by key) do not have to be processed, only the last ones. So when one process finished it would be ideal that Spark Streaming skip all events that are not the current last ones (by key).

I'm not sure that the solution could be done using only Spark Streaming API. As I understand Spark Streaming, DStream RDD will accumulate and be processed one by one and do not considerate if there are others afterwards.

Possible solutions:

- Using only Spark Streaming API but I'm not sure how. `updateStateByKey` seems to be a solution. But I'm not sure that it will work properly when DStream RDD accumulate and you have to only process lasts events by key.
- Have two Spark Streaming pipelines. One to get last updated event by key, store that in a map or a database. The second pipeline processes events only if they are the last ones as indicate by the other pipeline. Sub questions:

  - Could two pipelines share the same `sparkStreamingContext` and process the same DStream at different speed (low processing vs high)?
  - Is it easily possible to share values (map for example) between pipelines without using an external database? I think accumulator/broadcast could work but between two pipelines I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that streaming is a continuous process it is hard to define what "last" means in this context. However, assuming that you want to process last event within given period of time, for example run processing every 10 seconds and take only last event for each key in this 10 seconds frame - there are couple of possible ways.

#### Window approach

One of options is to make **window** on `DStream`:

```
val windowStream = dStream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(10))
windowStream.forEachRDD { /* process only latest events */ }
```

in this case windowStream will have RDD that combines key/values from all RDDs in last 10 seconds and you can access all of them in `forEachRDD` as if you had them in single RDD initially. The drawback is that it wouldn't provide any information on ordering of events on how they came into stream, but you may either have event time information in values or reuse offset from Kafka

#### updateStateByKey approach

Basically as you suggested - it would allow you to accumulate values.
Databricks have a good example on how to do this [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html)

While they do accumulation in example, you could just update value for key instead

#### Kafka log compaction

While this wouldn't replace need of handling it on Spark side, if you keep events in Kafka for some time you might want to consider using Kafka's [Log Compaction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Log+Compaction)
It wouldn't guarantee that duplicates are not getting into Spark streaming from Kafka, but will reduce number of stored events in Kafka by keeping only latest keys in the tail of the log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that my question is misleading. The main issue is when there is latency and the queue of RDD in the DStream, how to skip them more easily. I need a view of the last events by a certain key and just do the long process on events that correspond to last events by user id and skip the other.

Comment: Spark streaming won't do it for you automatically, but `updateStateByKey` is closest to what you want. If you implement update function to store only the latest event - it will do the trick.